# sql php find field value from updated row

Tags: php, sql

Say I have this loop:

```
foreach ($array as $a) {
    if ($a == $b) { 
        mysql_query("UPDATE table SET this = 'that' WHERE id='$a'");
        }
    }
```

And a table...

```
id    this    blah
------------------------
1     that    54
2     that    73
3     there   27
```

Inside that loop, I also want to find the value stored in the tables `blah` field from the current record that is being updated.

Whats the most effective way to do this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can have your query consist of multiple statements, and the last statement is what is used for the "results".

So, you can just add a "select" statement to the end of the update query and treat it like a normal select statement:

```
UPDATE table SET this = 'that' WHERE id='$a'; SELECT blah from [your table] WHERE id = '$a'
```

The advantage with this method is that it doesn't require an additional DB call.

Of course, you will want to be escaping the values put into the SQL statements to prevent SQL injection, but that's another matter.

Comment: is this ok though that im updating and querying the db for each loop instance?

Comment: It depends on how many times you go through the loop, really. If it's a lot, you will want to do 1 SELECT after all the updates are done, and you may want to batch the updates. On the other hand, if it's a small number of loop iterations, then it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

This was my <s>first</s> second SO answer which I felt needed revising. Searching around, I found a much better answer to your question.

From the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/700800/1085891) for question: [SQL: Update a row and returning a column value with 1 query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700786/sql-update-a-row-and-returning-a-column-value-with-1-query)

> You want the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause
>
> ```
> UPDATE Items SET Clicks = Clicks + 1 
> OUTPUT INSERTED.Name 
> WHERE Id = @Id
> ```

Similar question: [Is there a way to SELECT and UPDATE rows at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497464/is-there-a-way-to-select-and-update-rows-at-the-same-time)

**Old Answer**

Add a `SELECT` statement to the end of your `UPDATE` query.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET this = 'that' WHERE id='$a'; SELECT blah WHERE id='$a';");
```

This prevents you from ensuring the update took place since `mysql_query` only returns the last statement's result.

You could also write a custom function that performs both statements but, for instance, won't preform the `SELECT` if the `UPDATE` failed, etc.

** Skeleton Function - Not Tested **

```
function MyUpdate($query, $id){ 
    $retVal = "-1" // some default value
    $uResult = mysql_query("UPDATE table SET this = 'that' WHERE id='$a'");

    if( $uResult )
    $result= mysql_query('SELECT blah WHERE id=$a');
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        $retVal = $result;
    }
    return $retVal;
}
```