# SELECT a cell and UPDATE at the same time?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've got a SQL Server table in which I have a column where I would like to select the current value and increment by one, is there a way to do this in a single query? This in order to mitigate the chance, however small it might be, that someone else gets the same number.

Something along the lines of this pseudo code:

```
SELECT NumSeriesCurrent 
FROM NumSeries 
(UPDATE NumSeries SET NumSeriesCurrent = NumSeriesCurrent+1) 
WHERE NumSeriesKey='X'
```

Comment: `UPDATE NumSeries SET NumSeriesCurrent += 1 WHERE NumSeriesKey='X'`? Or you don't mean that?

Comment: @MartinSmith Well, that takes care of the updating, but I still won't get the value in NumSeriesCurrent previous to the update?

Comment: Nice. Can it be done in mySql?

Comment: @EASI - To simulate the `OUTPUT` clause in MySQL you need to use a trigger that returns a result AFAIK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to SELECT and UPDATE rows at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497464/is-there-a-way-to-select-and-update-rows-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update the value and get the value in `NumSeriesCurrent` previous to the update you can use

```
UPDATE NumSeries 
SET NumSeriesCurrent += 1
OUTPUT DELETED.NumSeriesCurrent
WHERE NumSeriesKey='X'
```

Comment: Didn't know about the *OUTPUT* part... +1