# How to select and update selected rows in a single sql query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, transactions, petapoco

I have a table named `Car`

```
Table car ( id int NOT NULL, plate int NOT NULL, sent_to_server bit NOT NULL );
```

I want to select all Cars which are not sent to server yet

```
SELECT * 
FROM   car 
WHERE  sent_to_server = 0;
```

Then I should update my DB

```
UPDATE car 
SET    sent_to_server = 1 
WHERE  sent_to_server = 0;
```

I have multiple threads so this wont work (multiple threads are reading and writing to the 
database at the same time -(im using sql server))

How can I execute 2 queries in One Query ?
Or is there a better solution !?

note: i'm using C# with petapoco library (if it matters !)

Comment: Why do you need that SELECT exactly?

Comment: i what the to send the Cars which are not sent to server yet .

Comment: its a client server application and a server tracks multiple client apps .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as you are using SQL Server 2005 or later you can make use of `OUTPUT` in a single query.

```
UPDATE Car
SET    sent_to_server = 1 
OUTPUT Inserted.id, Inserted.plate
WHERE  sent_to_server = 0;
```

This will update the rows where `sent_to_server` is zero and return the modified rows. No need for a transaction.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35312/1)

Comment: `UPDATE Car
SET    sent_to_server = 1 
OUTPUT Inserted.*
WHERE  sent_to_server = 0;` also works . its great !, thanks .

Comment: @user1575632 - Yes, the `*` also works but there's no need to return _all_ the table fields, you already know what the `sent_to_server` result will be ;) Only returning the information you need keeps the query as fast as possible.

Comment: @Tony, is there any way to translate this to MySQL?

Comment: @EricK Unfortunately not, as far as I'm aware, without using a transaction or the [GUID batch answer to this question from Eduardo Molteni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22084191/243925)

Comment: it's risky, because it's update the rows before sending it to the server, so if anything happens in the server u will not be able to get this data again to send it to the server.

Comment: @MohamedOmera True, but they were only asking how to update the database and get the result in a single query. Distributed transactions where multiple systems need to be kept in sync are beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use transaction.
Place your both queries in below code

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
select * from car where sent_to_server = 0;
 update car set sent_to_server = 1 where  sent_to_server = 0;
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

By default tansaction will lock the table to read for other connection, so other thread will not be able to read the result untill the transaction is not commited.

Comment: it did not work with my library(petapoco in C#) . but it helped . petapoco supports transactions .

Comment: Does TRANSACTION lock without a TABLOCKX on the select?

Answer (score 1):

Another idea to @Tony's answer, it's to change the `sent_to_server` column type to a Guid, and put there the processed batch number.

Example (pseudocode):

```
var batch = new Guid();
update car set sent_to_server = @batch where sent_to_server is null;    
select * from car where sent_to_server = @batch;
```